# Defining a vector within a custom class

Tags: c++, class, visual-c++, vector, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to simply use a vector within one of my classes. When trying to access the vector it tells me that it's undefined (but I've defined it in my header).

I have two classes, Person and Dog. A person can own one or more dogs so I want to add each dog a person owns into an array. This should be real simple so this problem is really starting to get to me. Here's some code:

The class Person.cpp:

```
#include "Person.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Person::Person(string name, string address, int age)
    :name(name),
    address(address),
    age(age)
    {}
int Person::getAge(){
    return age;
}
std::string Person::getDogInfo(int index){
}
void Person::addDog(string dogName, string breed){
    dogCollection.push_back(Dog(dogName, breed));
}
std::vector<Dog> getDogs(){
    return dogCollection;  //dogCollection undefined error here
}
```

And here's Person.h:

```
#ifndef Person_H
#define Person_H
#include <vector>
#include "Dog.h"
using namespace std;
class Person{
    public:
        Person(string name, string address, int age);
        string getName(){return name};
        string getAddress(){return address};
        void addDog(string dogName, string breed);
        string getDogInfo(int index);
        std::vector<Dog> getDogs();
        int getAge();

    private:
        string name;
        string address;
        int age;
        std::vector<Dog> dogCollection;
};
#endif
```

If you want to have a look at my dog classes I'll paste them as well:

Dog.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "dog.h"

Dog::Dog(string dogName, string breed)
    :dogName(dogName),
        breed(breed){}

std::string Dog::Dog.getDogName(){
return dogName;
}

std::string Dog::Dog.getBreed(){
return breed;
}
```

and Dog.h:

```
#ifndef Dog_H
#define Dog_H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Dog{
public:
    Dog(std::string dogName, std::string breed);
    std::string getDogName();
    std::string getBreed();
private:
    std::string dogName;
    std::string breed;
};
#endif
```

Also, I just want to add that this is no homework. I'm used to java and I'm only trying to learn some C++ since I need it for future work.

EDIT: Updated the code

Comment: You're both `using namespace std` and also qualifying `vector` as `std::vector`.  What happens if you get rid of the `using` directive?

Comment: As a side note: You should use an [initialization list](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.6) in your constructor.

Comment: I bet thats not the first error, since thats not an error, and I see other errors the compiler would show first.  Fix the first error(s) and this one will go away.  Namely, your includes are in the wrong places.

Comment: Your constructor doesn't do what you think it does.  Besides the erroneous vector assignment, you are just assigning local variables to themselves, leaving the member variables untouched.

Comment: You are editing the code so much that previous answers are becoming irrelevant. It is better if you isolate the problem in a smaller code sample and post a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is incorrect (and unrequired):

```
dogCollection = new std::vector<Dog>; // Remove this line.
```

as `dogCollection` is not a `std::vector<Dog>*`.

---

This is also incorrect:

```
void Person::addDog(string dogName, string breed){
    Dog *newDog = new Dog(dogName, breed);
    dogCollection.push_back(newDog);
}
```

as `dogCollection` contains `Dog` instances, not `Dog*`. Change to:

```
void Person::addDog(string dogName, string breed){
    dogCollection.push_back(Dog(dogName, breed));
}
```

---

There is a problem with all of constructors:

```
Person::Person(string name, string address, int age){
    name=name;
    address=address;
    age=age;
}
```

This is assigning the argument `name` to itself: it is not assigning to the member `name`. Same for `address` and `age` and similarly for the constructors of the other classes. Use initializer list:

```
Person::Person(string name, string address, int age) :
    name(name),
    address(address),
    age(age)
{}
```

---

This method does not return a `std::string`:

```
string Person::getDogInfo(int index){
}
```

EDIT:

Missing class qualifier:

```
std::vector<Dog> getDogs(){
    return dogCollection;  //dogCollection undefined error here
}
```

means this is just a free function, with no association to class `Person` and therefore no access to `dogCollection`.

Change to:

```
std::vector<Dog> Person::getDogs(){
    return dogCollection;
}
```

Comment: I thought (altho wasn't sure) the dogCollection = new std::vector<Dog>; was unnessecary so that was not in my "first" attempt. I've removed it not but still gives me the same error later in the code

Comment: Seems like I had alot of errors. Thanks alot for your pointers! still getting "undefined" error on the return value in function getDogs() (which returns the vector). I've edited my post with the changes I made. Can you see anything wrong with that metod or when im defining the vector?

Answer (score 2):

```
    std::vector<Dog> dogCollection;  // here im defining dogCollection, no error here!
```

There actually *is* an problem here - class `Dog` isn't known to the compiler at this point.

You can solve this by either including `Dog.h` before `Person.h` in `Person.cpp`, or **better** add an `#include "Dog.h"` at the top of `Person.h`.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your code, and most of the other answers have pointed them out - mostly regarding the use of `new` when it should not be used.  (Are you a C# programmer, moving to C++?)

However, there are problems with the `#include` directives as well.  As @Bo mentioned, since `Person` uses `Dog`, you should include that header in `Person.h`.  But `Person` also uses `vector` so that header should be included there as well.  So `Person.h` should start with...

```
#include <vector>
#include "Dog.h"
```

Then in `Person.cpp` you don't have to include those files.

As a general rule (you can learn about "forward declaration" later), any types referenced in a header should be `#include`d in that header.